# how to obtain substrings those are within the angular brackets in a string

Tags: c#, .net, string

i think this would be really silly question , but iam not succesful with extratic srtings those within the angular barkets in a sentence .

```
var str = "MR. {Name} of {Department} department stood first in {Subjectname}"
```

i need to obtain the **substrings (as array)** those are within the angular brakets

like strArray should contain **{Name,Department,Subjectname}** from the above given string

Answer (score 8):

Noting the use of `var` in your question, I will assume that you are using .NET 3.5. 
The **one line** of code below should do the trick.

```
string[] result = Regex.Matches(str, @"\{([^\}]*)\}").Cast<Match>().Select(o => o.Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    List<string> fields = new List<string>();
    foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(str, @"\{([^\}]*)\}")) {
        fields.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
```

Or for formatting (filling in the blanks) - see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322037#1322103).

Comment: yeah that's a whole lot less effort

Answer (score 0):

Use String.IndexOf("{") to get the index of the first open tag and String.IndexOf("}") to get the index of the first close tag.  Then use the other string functions to get it out (substring, remove etc)...while there are still tags