# How do I make the params keyword usage similar to writing to the Console

Tags: c#, arguments, parameters

In relation to my last question ([Is there an easier way of passing a group of variables as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588135/is-there-an-easier-way-of-passing-a-group-of-variables-as-an-array))

I was trying to pass string variables to a method to write to a stream, rather than doing the writing in each individual method.

The use of the params keyword is obviously a solution, however by using it I believe I can't do things like this:

```
Write("hello {0}",var1);
```

Which without makes the code quite messy. Is there a way to force this feature to my own methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void MyMethod(string format, params object[] obj) {
    var formattedString = String.Format(format, obj);
    // do something with it...
}
```

Comment: You may have missed the question? What I'd like to be able to do is pass arguments into a string when passing the whole thing as an argument to another method.

All I can do at the moment is this:

Write("Hello ",var1);

which when dealing with long strings becomes very messy.

I'd like to be able to do this:

Write("Hello {0}",var1);

Comment: George: I can't see what you can't do right now. The output of `String.Format` is a string with `{0}`, `{1}` replaced by value of the respective argument.

Comment: Ignore the comment, I just understood what you did :V

Thanks.

Comment: George: This is exactly what he's doing here.  You get "formattedString" to work with, which will put that together for you.

Answer (score 1):

A method that has the `params` keyword can be passed an explicit array or an inline array.

Therefore, you can write the following:

```
public static void Write(params string[] stringsToWrite) {
    //...
    writer.WriteLine("Hello {0} {1} {2}", stringsToWrite);
    //...
}
```

**EDIT** Your question is unclear.  If your asking whether a `params` array parameter can be given only one value, the answer is yes.

For example:

```
Write("myString");
```

The reason that many `params` methods in .Net have separate overloads that take just one parameter is to avoid creating an array for optimization reasons.