# C# string format flag or modifier to lowercase param

Tags: c#, string, formatting

Is it possible to specify some kind of flag or modifier on a string format param to make it lower case or upper case?

Example of what I want:

```
String.Format("Hi {0:touppercase}, you have {1} {2:tolowercase}.", "John", 6, "Apples");
```

Wanted output:

> Hi JOHN, you have 6 apples.

PS: Yes I know that I can change the case of the param before using it in the string format, but I don't want this.

Comment: I know you don't want it, but I can't see why just calling .tolower() or .toupper() on the string params is a problem.

Comment: " I can't see why just calling .tolower() or .toupper() on the string params is a problem" - for example, data binding.

Comment: I've got the same situation. The reason .ToLower() won't work for me is that the formatting string is coming from a database (ie, it's configurable by the end user).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There's only padding and allignment formating... So the easy way is like you said, use `"John".ToUpper()` or `"John".ToLower()`.

Another solution could be create a custom `IFormatProvider`, to provide the string format you want.

This is how will look the `IFormatProvider` and the string.Format call.

```cs
public class CustomStringFormat : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        string result = arg.ToString();
        switch (format?.ToUpperInvariant()) // culture independent
        {
            case "U": return result.ToUpper();
            case "L": return result.ToLower();
            //more custom formats
            default: return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And the call will look like:

```cs
String.Format(new CustomStringFormat(), "Hi {0:U}", "John");
```

Comment: Is there any way of doing this within the confines of a DisplayFormatAttribute?

Comment: If format is not specified there will be `NullReferenceException`, so null check condition in `Format()` method should be added.

Answer (score 8):

In short, no; AFAIK you'd have to fix the source values, or use your own replacement to `string.Format`. Note that if you are passing in a custom culture (to `string.Format`) you may want to use `culture.TextInfo.ToLower(s)`, rather than just `s.ToLower()`.

Comment: I was just going to suggest writing your own string formatter.

Comment: Indeed - you could probably *start* here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322037#1322103, but lots more to do...

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question trying to solve the same exact problem but with the difference the values being formatted were coming from Enums so I came up with a generic enough implementation that could be used for any type and dynamically invoked any `string` class method (such as `ToLower` or `ToUpper` but could be used for other methods too).

Of course one could implement `IFormattable` on the class they wish to format but in the case of `string` and `Enum` that is not possible so I created a wrapper class:

```
public class Formattable<T> : IFormattable
{
    private T obj;

    public Formattable(T obj)
    {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        var formatted = obj.ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format)) return formatted;

        var method = typeof(string).GetMethod(format, new Type[0]);

        return (string)method.Invoke(formatted, new object[0]);
    }
}

public static class FormattableExtension
{
    public static Formattable<T> Formattable<T>(this T o)
    {
        return new Formattable<T>(o);
    }
}
```

You then can use this while formatting your parameters like:

```
String.Format(
  "This will make {0:ToLower} lowercase while {0:ToUpper} uppercase", 
  obj.Formattable()
);
```