# WPF/XAML: How to make all text upper case in TextBlock?

Tags: wpf, xaml, uppercase, textblock

I want all characters in a TextBlock to be displayed in uppercase

```
<TextBlock Name="tbAbc"
           FontSize="12"
           TextAlignment="Center"
           Text="Channel Name"
           Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static r:RibbonSkinResources.RibbonGroupLabelFontColorBrushKey}}" />
```

The strings are taken through Binding. I don't want to make the strings uppercase in the dictionary itself.

Comment: see [C# string format flag or modifier to lowercase param](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839649/c-sharp-string-format-flag-or-modifier-to-lowercase-param)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF/XAML: how to make all text upper case / capital?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762485/wpf-xaml-how-to-make-all-text-upper-case-capital)

Answer (score 47):

Or use

```
Typography.Capitals="AllSmallCaps"
```

in your `TextBlock` definition.

See here: [MSDN - Typography.Capitals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.typography.capitals(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT:**

This does not work in **Windows Phone 8.1**, only in Windows 8.1 ...

Comment: This doesn't work, capitals will be large capitals and lower case characters will be small capitals.

Comment: This breaks when using custom font.

Answer (score 17):

Implement a custom converter.

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
// ...
public class StringToUpperConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is string )
        {
            return ((string)value).ToUpper();
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then include that in your XAML as a resource:

```
<local:StringToUpperConverter  x:Key="StringToUpperConverter"/>
```

And add it to your binding:

```
Converter={StaticResource StringToUpperConverter}
```

Comment: You may not want to use "value is string" in there.  Try   
   if (value != null)
   {
    return value.ToString().ToUpper(culture);
   }

Comment: @brenth - I prefer converters that work with a specific type only. If it doesn't get that type, return the value untouched. That might be a little cautious when it expects a string, but this is the pattern I prefer. Not that your suggestion wouldn't work perfectly well.

Comment: Just a friendly heads-up.  If `value` is `null`, then `value is string` will equate to false so your null check can be removed.  You can also remove your cast and use the following syntax instead: `if(value is string stringValue){ return stringValue.ToUpper(); }`.  I've also added my own answer that uses a single-line null-coalescing approach as well as making the converter a subclass of `MarkupExtension` so you don't need to add your converter to your resources. You can just use it directly as needed right in the binding. Feel free to check it out! :)

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe - always appreciate friendly improvements, and will take a look at markup extensions for future applications also. Thanks for the info and +1 on your answer also.

Answer (score 10):

You can use an attached property like this:

```
public static class TextBlock
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CharacterCasingProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "CharacterCasing",
        typeof(CharacterCasing),
        typeof(TextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            CharacterCasing.Normal,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.NotDataBindable,
            OnCharacterCasingChanged));

    private static readonly DependencyProperty TextProxyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "TextProxy",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(TextBlock),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnTextProxyChanged));

    private static readonly PropertyPath TextPropertyPath = new PropertyPath("Text");


    public static void SetCharacterCasing(DependencyObject element, CharacterCasing value)
    {
        element.SetValue(CharacterCasingProperty, value);
    }

    public static CharacterCasing GetCharacterCasing(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (CharacterCasing)element.GetValue(CharacterCasingProperty);
    }

    private static void OnCharacterCasingChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock textBlock)
        {
            if (BindingOperations.GetBinding(textBlock, TextProxyProperty) == null)
            {
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(
                    textBlock,
                    TextProxyProperty,
                    new Binding
                    {
                        Path = TextPropertyPath,
                        RelativeSource = RelativeSource.Self,
                        Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnTextProxyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        d.SetCurrentValue(System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.TextProperty, Format((string)e.NewValue, GetCharacterCasing(d)));

        string Format(string text, CharacterCasing casing)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                return text;
            }

            switch (casing)
            {
                case CharacterCasing.Normal:
                    return text;
                case CharacterCasing.Lower:
                    return text.ToLower();
                case CharacterCasing.Upper:
                    return text.ToUpper();
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(casing), casing, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then usage in xaml will look like:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox" Text="abc" />
    <TextBlock local:TextBlock.CharacterCasing="Upper" Text="abc" />
    <TextBlock local:TextBlock.CharacterCasing="Upper" Text="{Binding ElementName=TextBox, Path=Text}" />
    <Button local:TextBlock.CharacterCasing="Upper" Content="abc" />
    <Button local:TextBlock.CharacterCasing="Upper" Content="{Binding ElementName=TextBox, Path=Text}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This is a great solution if the textblock in question is already using a converter.

Comment: Great solution as it doesn't imply you to change the content of the element.

Comment: This is a great solution because it can solely be controlled via external styles/property setters: <Setter Property="local:TextBlock.CharacterCasing" Value="Upper" />

Comment: BTW, you don't have to nest your `if` statements.  You can use an `&&` operator to first check if it's a `TextBlock` and if so, check its text binding. Also, in newer versions of C#, they recommend using pattern matching against null instead of equality checking. (i.e. instead of `if(bla == null){ ... }` they suggest `if(bla is null){ ... }` (or `is not null` if that's what you need). Not sure if it's just for readability or if it even alters the IL, but that seems to be the direction of all their newest/latest code.

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If it's not a big deal you could use **TextBox** instead of **TextBlock** like this:

```
<TextBox CharacterCasing="Upper" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: It's not really an acceptable answer though because the question asks about TextBlock.

Comment: @StephenDrew I was **not** asking him to accept my answer, just letting  him know that he should accept one ( the one that helped him the most - that's all about this site, right?). In my opinion, the one with the converter is a good answer. (mine is just an alternative).

Comment: On TextBox, setting the character casing property to true only affects manually typed text. So setting IsReadOnly to true at the same time eliminates the CharacterCasing properties usefulness to this particular use-case. I didn't know the CharacterCasing property existed on TextBox though so I learned something here!

Comment: @HDL_CinC_Dragon is correct, CharacterCasing="Upper" on the TextBox element will only apply to newly typed text into the element. It won't apply it to an already existing "text" value unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

While there's already a great answer here that uses a converter, I'm providing an alternative implementation that simplifies the conversion to a single line (thanks to null coalescing), as well as making it a subclass of `MarkupExtension` so it's easier to use in XAML.

Here's the converter...

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace IntuoSoft.Wpf.Converters {

    [ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]
    public class CapitalizationConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            => (value as string)?.ToUpper() ?? value; // If it's a string, call ToUpper(), otherwise, pass it through as-is.

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            => throw new NotSupportedException();

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;
    }
}
```

And here's how you use it (Note: This assumes the above namespace is prefixed with `is` in your XAML):

```xml
<TextBlock Text={Binding SomeValue, Converter={is:CapitalizationConverter}}" />
```

Because it's a `MarkupExtension` subclass, you can simply use it right where/when it's needed. No need to define it in the resources first.

Answer (score 2):

I use a character casing value converter:

```
class CharacterCasingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var s = value as string;
        if (s == null)
            return value;

        CharacterCasing casing;
        if (!Enum.TryParse(parameter as string, out casing))
            casing = CharacterCasing.Upper;

        switch (casing)
        {
            case CharacterCasing.Lower:
                return s.ToLower(culture);
            case CharacterCasing.Upper:
                return s.ToUpper(culture);
            default:
                return s;
        }
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```