# pass string template to function c#

Tags: c#, string

How can I pass string template to function?

I`m creating general usage library.

At this point main application needs to give template for email and library must add specific value at specific place in email.

```
void SomeFunction(string Template)
{
   string OtherString = "This text is inserted";


   string result - how to set the value of this string - Some text This text is inserted aa?
}


string Template = "Some text {need insert here} aa";

SomeFunction(Template);
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1322103/29407

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this:

```
string otherString = "inserted value";
string template = string.Format("Some text {0} aa", otherString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string Template = "Some Text {need insert here} aa";

string InYourfunction = Template.Replace("{need insert here}", "whatever you want to replace here with");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for:

```
void SomeFunction(string templateString)
{
   string otherString = "This text is inserted";


   string result = string.Format(templateString, otherString);
}


string template = "Some text {0} aa";

SomeFunction(template);
```

However, why would you do it like this, instead of more simpler and straight-forward option provided by [Jens Kloster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15129554/219516)?

What if you pass an incorrect templateString to your SomeFunction e.g. passing "My test: {0},{1}" while SomeFunction expects only "My test: {0}"?