# Convert Regex.Replace into conditional replace

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching, str-replace

I'm currently working with a piece of code in c#/Asp.net.

It uses a regex replace function structured like this:

```
return regex.Replace(pattern, match =>
{
    // do something
    return something;
});

An example pattern might be "This is a {sample} bit of text where the items in the brackets are {replaced}"
```

This form of replace syntax seems to be all or nothing — it gets all matches and will replace all matches with something.

Here's the full code which was posted by Mark Gravell:

[How can I create a more user-friendly string.format syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322037/how-can-i-create-a-more-user-friendly-string-format-syntax)

However, I need to be able to conditionally replace — get matches, iterate through them, and decide to replace or not.

**Example**

Given the input string:

"You are {age} years old and your first name is {firstName} and yourlast name is {lastName}.

**Usage**

string s = Format("You are {age} years old and your first name is {firstName} and yourlast name is {lastName}.",
        new {age = 18, firstName = "Foo"});

**Current output**

"You are 18 years old and your first name is Foo and yourlast name is ."

**Desired output**

"You are 18 years old and your first name is Foo and yourlast name is {lastName}."

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Please make your question concrete: what text have you got and what do you need to get in the end? The snippet above looks like a sample code from the docs, what have *you* tried? What is your *problem*?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I recently posted the question in a lot more detail and got slayed for a lack of clarity. I am writing an extension that will replace the properties in the brackets with properties I supply - like string.format. The above code will replace all and there is no option to opt out. I wan't to be able to find matches then choose to replace. I don't need extensive code, just an idea as to how to separate out the replace and match functionality.

Comment: In the code I linked to, just use `var pattern = @"(?<={).*?(?=})";` for it work with no other changes in the further code. Certainly, you may enhance it by using `@"{(.*?)}"` or `@"{([^{}]*)}"` pattern and then using `m => $"{{{variablesDictionary[m.Groups[1].Value]}}}"`.

Comment: Also, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/Bl17a0).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I used the pattern but got nothing back - just empty brackets for everything. I've added a link to the piece of code I'm trying to make a change to which will help explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: John, right now, we all understand what you are trying to do, but it is not at all clear what is wrong with *your* code. Once you specify the exact problem, I will be glad to reopen/answer your question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - thanks for your help - the current code replaces all matching properties but at the same time removes any brackets that are not matched. What I need is to replace all the the matched properties, but leave the unmatched properties as they were.

Comment: John, I shared a demo link. It has `m => dct.ContainsKey(m.Groups[1].Value) ?
   $"{{{dct[m.Groups[1].Value]}}}" : m.Value` part: if the value in between `{...}` is known, if it is present in the dictionary, it is replaced. Else, `m.Value`, the whole match, is pasted back.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - using the match.value worked - thanks for that.